# Block placer/beans conflict with previously created blocks

Tags: blocks

I'm running drupal 7. I'm currently working on a project that was abandoned by it's previous dev, and the client is attempting to duct tape it back together. My current issue:

I have a use case for the module [Blocks Placer](https://www.drupal.org/project/blocks_placer). The client wants to be able to add call to action blocks that they have previously created to pages that their staff will make. They want these blocks to be able to be placed in various areas on the page, or not at all.

The site is also currently using blocks in various regions. There's around 30 blocks, and 10 superfish menus created by the superfish module. When the blocks placer module is enabled, the /admin/structure/blocks page is replaced with a page that only shows created beans, and no blocks whatsoever. Before I created a bean, the page showed every region empty, including the disabled blocks region. After creating a bean, it was the only thing that shows up.

Is there a way to have this page show beans and blocks, or a separate page that shows only blocks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be interested in a suggestion about some other module to take care of the "They want these blocks to be able to be placed in various areas on the page, or not at all." part of your question? It may reduce (or eliminate?) the need for your "Blocks Placer" module (and hence the conflict you seem to run into)?